# Moving formatted data in Salesforce rich text field into Wordpress

Tags: formatting

I am new to moving Salesforce data dynamically into Wordpress. I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve data in a rich content Salesforce field and pull it into Wordpress without losing the formatting.

Comment: It depends on how Salesforce applies the formatting (is it just HTML?) and where you want to put it in WordPress. If it’s just HTML then there shouldn’t be any issue.